# Websocket from Chrome Extension to Chrome Debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, websocket, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am writing a plugin for Chrome (manifest v3). It should create a WebSocket connection between the Service Worker and the Chrome Debugger, so that I can control a page with puppeteer.

```
const browserDebugger = await (
await fetch(http://localhost:9223/json/version, { mode: "no-cors" })
).json();
const debuggerURL = browserDebugger.webSocketDebuggerUrl;
const chromeWebsocket = new WebSocket(debuggerURL);
```

I am getting the following error in the last line:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9223/devtools/browser/2cd7eac1-a1e0-41ed-9eac-8ba8d0befc9e' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  ....
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; connect-src http://localhost:9223/ ws://localhost:9223/ http://localhost:4821/ ws://localhost:4821/"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "http://localhost:4821/",
    "http://localhost:9223/"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "debugger",
    "tabs",
  ]
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Try debugging via `chrome://net-export`

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't understand, how I can use this information. It's just a json without any data about error:
```{
      "params": {
        "message": "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403",
        "net_error": -2
      },
      "phase": 0,
      "source": {
        "id": 336,
        "start_time": "1192068373",
        "type": 1
      },
      "time": "1192068374",
      "type": 511
    },```

Comment: Solution was to add `--remote-allow-origins=*` to start parameters of the chrome.